# REST Call Returns Tons of Unnecessary Metadata. How do I Just Get the Column Values?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I want to get the values stored in my List.  Is there a way to make a call that **only** returns a string like:

```
[
 item1 [ID, Title ...]
 ,item2 [ID, Title ...]
 ,item3 [ID, Title ...]
 ...
]
```

When I make this call, I get a ridiculously long response; 99% of it is metadata or different versions of REST the call that I made.  The data I'm interested is between 25-50 characters, but this returns 3000.

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')/items(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get specific column values from the list, you can use select query like:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')/items(1)?$select=ID,Title
```

Where ID and Title are internal name of your list columns. You can get internal names of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

You can specify multiple column names (comma separated) in select query as per your requirements.

Comment: I'm getting similar results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong; I'm very new to REST and AJAX.

I asked for verbose metadata:

- contentType: 'application/json;odata=**verbose**'

Changed to:

- contentType: 'application/json;odata=**nometadata**'